# ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (2537)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

**The dataframe looks like:**

```
ward_wise_gender_df
```

```
   ward male    female  other
0   10  10.0    1.0 10.0
1   11  11.0    11.0    10.0
2   7   7.0 7.0 7.0
3   6   6.0 6.0 6.0
4   4   4.0 4.0 4.0
... ... ... ... ...
2532    3   1.0 2.0 2.0
2533    6   1.0 2.0 1.0
2534    7   4.0 2.0 2.0
2535    4   2.0 2.0 2.0
2536    3   3.0 3.0 2.0
2537 rows × 4 columns
```

**My code looks like:**

```
crosstab_table = pd.crosstab(index=ward_wise_gender_df['ward'], columns=['male', 'female', 'other'], values=[ward_wise_gender_df['male'], ward_wise_gender_df['female'], ward_wise_gender_df['other']], aggfunc='sum')
```

**My Issue looks like:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 crosstab_table = pd.crosstab(index=ward_wise_gender_df['ward'], columns=['male', 'female', 'other'], values=[ward_wise_gender_df['male'], ward_wise_gender_df['female'], ward_wise_gender_df['other']], aggfunc='sum')
      2 crosstab_table

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py:682, in crosstab(index, columns, values, rownames, colnames, aggfunc, margins, margins_name, dropna, normalize)
    676 from pandas import DataFrame
    678 data = {
    679     **dict(zip(unique_rownames, index)),
    680     **dict(zip(unique_colnames, columns)),
    681 }
--> 682 df = DataFrame(data, index=common_idx)
    684 if values is None:
    685     df["__dummy__"] = 0

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:664, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    658     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    659         data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    660     )
    662 elif isinstance(data, dict):
    663     # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 664     mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    665 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    666     import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:493, in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    489     else:
    490         # dtype check to exclude e.g. range objects, scalars
    491         arrays = [x.copy() if hasattr(x, "dtype") else x for x in arrays]
--> 493 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:123, in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    120         index = ensure_index(index)
    122     # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway
--> 123     arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
    124     # _homogenize ensures
    125     #  - all(len(x) == len(index) for x in arrays)
    126     #  - all(x.ndim == 1 for x in arrays)
   (...)
    129 
    130 else:
    131     index = ensure_index(index)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:620, in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
    615             val = lib.fast_multiget(val, oindex._values, default=np.nan)
    617         val = sanitize_array(
    618             val, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False
    619         )
--> 620         com.require_length_match(val, index)
    622     homogenized.append(val)
    624 return homogenized

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py:571, in require_length_match(data, index)
    567 """
    568 Check the length of data matches the length of the index.
    569 """
    570 if len(data) != len(index):
--> 571     raise ValueError(
    572         "Length of values "
    573         f"({len(data)}) "
    574         "does not match length of index "
    575         f"({len(index)})"
    576     )

ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (2537)
```

**The Length of columns:**

```
print(len(ward_wise_gender_df['ward']))
print(len(ward_wise_gender_df['male']))
print(len(ward_wise_gender_df['female']))
print(len(ward_wise_gender_df['other']))
```

**Output:**

```
2537
2537
2537
2537
```

Comment: `ward_wise_gender_df.groupby('ward', as_index=False)[['male', 'female', 'other']].sum()`